# Running commands through a Dockerfile once container is running

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to setup a Dockerfile for keycloak and I want to run some commands once my container has started

The reason for this is once the server is started, I want to add some custom configuration each time the Dockerfile is run. I've tried using the "RUN" command however since my container hasn't started when I use the run command, it causes the whole Dockerfile to bomb out

I thought to run a command after the container has started, I could use "CMD" however when I even try running `CMD ["echo", "hi"]` or `CMD ["sh", "echo", "hi"]`, I get an error "invalid option echo"

Is there a way to get commands to run once a container is running and if so how?

Comment: Can you add your actual `Dockerfile` and `docker run` to the question?  What’s the main process in your container?

Answer (score 0):

The way to define what your container does when you start it is to specify either `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`. These commands are executed when you use `docker run`. You can use `RUN` to perform various tasks during the build phase. Depending on what you want to do it may or may not be appropriate.

Try `CMD sh -c 'echo hi'` or `CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo hi"]`

The exec (list style) format is preferred but the shell format is also acceptable.

Also, keep in mind that the Dockerfile is used only for the build process. Containers are generally designed to be stateless. You shouldn't have to rebuild every time you change something in your application config.

Comment: `CMD` with no brackets automatically wraps its argument in `sh -c`.  (Also `RUN` and `ENTRYPOINT`, though it’s probably a bug for the latter.)